# MongoDB: Is it possible to SHA512 columns?

Tags: sql, mongodb, sha

Basically what I want to do is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE SHA2(myField, 512) =  'myValue';
```

Is this possible?

**Scenario**

1. I have this hashed string but I have a plain string in stored in DB.

Comment: This sounds backwards.  Why are you storing the plain-text version in the database, rather than the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do finds based on function evaluation on a field, in general. If you want to match on the hash and keep the plain string value, store the hash and the plain string value on the document.